# Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration, complex-numbers, greens-functions

In quantum field theory we always deal with complex integrals. They arise, e.g. when we calculate Feynman diagrams in either $T=0$, $T \neq 0$ and non-equilibrium formalism (or just Fourier transforms in any branch of physics). If we have free propagators in, e.g. self-energy diagrams, we often have expressions like $1/(x \pm i0)$ due to analytical properties of Green's functions.

In all QFT books, we learn about Sokhotski formula, which reads $$\frac{1}{x + i0} = \text{P}\frac 1 x - i \pi\delta(x) $$ If we apply it to $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x+i0}$$ we therefore get $- i \pi$.

On the other hand, we can seemingly compute this integral using the residue theorem. We can regularise it by adding $$\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} e^{- i \varepsilon x} \, ,$$ so we can close the contour in the lower half plane and get $- 2 \pi i$.

Integral regularization is certainly quite artificial trick. However, it is commonly and successfully used in quantum mechanics (and in Fourier transforms, e.g. of Coulomb potential) as well as Sokhotski formula. If I just put $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx e^{- i 0 x}}{x+i0}$$ into Mathematica, I get $- 2 \pi i$. So, I can't see how to resolve this contradiction.

Just to let you know - I also posted this question here
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2189979/sokhotski-plemelj-theorem

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic, I also posted this question there. However, this is a so common integral in QFT, so I think it's worth posting it here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it has been crossposted.

Comment: I do think there's a valid physics issue here as it's to clarify the use of a mathematical trick in a specific way in physics.  This might be a fair use of cross posting, and to be reasonable, the poster did indicate clearly they had cross posted.

Comment: @Qmechanic Could you give an idea how to answer such a question rather than vote here?

Comment: This question is probably suitable to the physics site because the *answer* needed here must discuss how the boundary conditions (which are often physically motivated) figure into the use of the SP formula.

Comment: That said, I'm really confused by what $i0$ means. The Sokhotski-Plemelj theorem is usually formulated with a limit as the imaginary part of the denominator approaches zero. Is that what you mean? I think you're getting confused by two things here, and fixing the notation would help.

Comment: @DanielSank what I mean by i0 is just $i \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \varepsilon$. This is the case, e.g. for a free retarded Green's function as it is nonzero at positive times at zero at negative times, so it's analytical in the upper complex frequency half-plane and has a pole in a lower half-plane

Comment: To have a concrete example, we can think about $1/(\omega + i0)$ like about a Fourier transform of a theta funtion $\theta(t)$. It's given by $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \theta(t) e^{i \omega t} = \int_0^{\infty} e^{i \omega t}$. This is not a good integral, but if we regularise it in this way $\lim\limits_{\alpha \rightarrow +0} \int_0^{\infty} e^{i \omega t - \alpha t}$, then we get $\lim\limits_{\alpha \rightarrow +0}\frac{i}{\omega + i \alpha}$, what I denote just $\frac{i}{\omega + i 0}$

Comment: You need to calculate the large circular boundary. The boundary contribution is $-i \pi$. The total circle is the residue which is $-2i \pi$. So use the contour the result is still the $-i\pi$.